# In Python how to add headers for a file after gzip before writing it

Tags: python, gzip, content-encoding

I am trying to open a javascript file, read it, gzip it and then write it back to another file.. able to do all that.. but how can set the "Content-Encoding : gzip" before writing the compressed content... here is the code:

```
import os, sys, mimetypes, zipfile, gzip, cStringIO
from optparse import OptionParser
def main():
    parser = OptionParser(usage='usage: %prog [options] src_file destination_file')
    parser.add_option('-x', '--expires', action='store_true', help='set far future expiry for all files')
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    if len(args) != 2:
        parser.error("incorrect number of arguments")
    name = os.path.normpath(args[0])
    des_file = os.path.normpath(args[1])

    try:
        s_file = open(name, 'r')
        content = s_file.read()

        compressed = cStringIO.StringIO()
        gz = gzip.GzipFile(filename=name,  mode='w', fileobj=compressed)
        gz.write(content)
        gz.close()
        s_file.close()

        o_file = open(des_file, 'w')
        ##
        ## BEFORE WRITING THE CONTENT INTO A FILE HOW WE ADD THE Content-Encoding
        ##
        o_file.write(compressed.getvalue())
        o_file.close()

    except (IOError, os.error), why:
        print 'Failed to read the file', filename, '\n Exception:', why
```

Comment: o_file.write("Content-Encoding: .....") ???

Comment: hmm, that just adds the an extra line in the gzip'ed file.. does not really add it to the file header!

Comment: There is no such think as content-encoding for a file. That's an HTTP header.

Comment: @jterrace thank you! just used urllib2

Answer (score 0):

That is usually determined by [whatever is serving the file.](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) Your job is usually limited to setting the correct file name extension (`.gz` in this case) when you create the file and configuring the server properly.